# Rails: Rendering a Superclass Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial

I have two classes (Impressions and Replies) which inherit from the parent class Comment:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  . . . .
end

class ImpressionsController < CommentsController
  . . . .
end

class RepliesController < CommentsController
  . . . .
end
```

In my view, I want them to render the same way. Right now, I'm approaching it like this:

```
<%= render @comment %>
```

Ideally, this would render the partial "/comments/_comment", but instead Rails want to render things like "/impressions/_impression" or "/replies/_replies." Is there any way to strong arm Rails into do "/comments/_comment"?

Comment: you have three different types, Impressions, Replies and Comments and you want to render them all as if they were the base class Comment?

Comment: Yep. Impressions and Replies are basically the same thing, though there are significant differences in the way their respective models handle them. The distinction is important on the back end, but on the front end, they can be treated the same way.

Comment: Maybe you could force the subclasses to the base: render @comment.becomes(Comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With :collection you can render a collection of objects. Given a single object you should us :object instead.

```
<%= render partial: '/comments/comment', object: @impression %>
```

The :as is not necessary as long as the partial is named 'comment'. If you name your partial e.g. 'my_comment' then @impression would be accessible via the local variable 'my_comment' and you would have to use :as to define a different local name.

However in your case I would prefer to define a partial path for the Impression and Replies model as follows (Rails >3.2.?):

```
class Impression < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...  

  def to_partial_path
    "comments/comment"
  end
end
```

Then you can use the standard rendering with an object or collection

```
<%= render @comment %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think smth like this can help:

```
<%= render :partial => '/comments/comment', :collection => @impressions,
           :as => :comment %>
```

Comment: Good to know about :as. I've been toying with this approach, though, and so far I haven't had any luck. The render turns out blank every time. I'll keep you posted if I figure anything out.

Comment: I just don't get it. According to my console, rails is definitely rendering '/comments/comment,' but it always turns up blank, even if the partial is full of static text. This led me to think that '@impressions' is being treated as null, but if I do something like '@impressions.first.title' immediately before rendering the partial, I get non-null results. Any other ideas about what could be going wrong?

Comment: Got it working. There are instances where I'm passing a single variable, such as '@impression' rather than '@impressions.' If I put it into an array like '[@impression]' then everything works well.